# Difference in results when using full dataset vs subset in lmer

Tags: r, multiple-regression, lme4-nlme

I have a dataset with the number of different species across multiple years and locations. I'm interested in seeing how abundance of each species has changed over time in each place. My data looks something like this (but 35000 rows):

```
Year   Place       Type of fruit  Number of fruits
2000   Orchard     Apple          5
2000   Beach       Apple          0
2000   Mountains   Apple          2
2001   Orchard     Apple          30
2001   Beach       Apple          3
2001   Mountains   Apple          3
2000   Orchard     Orange         18
2000   Beach       Orange         5
2000   Mountains   Orange         0
2001   Orchard     Orange         6
2001   Beach       Orange         1
2001   Mountains   Orange         5
2000   Orchard     Coconut        0
2000   Beach       Coconut        50
2000   Mountains   Coconut        0
2001   Orchard     Coconut        1
2001   Beach       Coconut        52
2001   Mountains   Coconut        2
```

I ran a test like this:

```
fit <- lmer(year~number + type + (1|place), data=fruits, REML=FALSE)
```

which gives me a result for each species.

If I run a separate test like this:

```
sepfit <- lmer(year~number + (1|place), data=subset(xmasdataover, species == "Apple"),
          REML=FALSE )
```

I get a different result for Apple than I got for it in the original combined analysis. What's the reason for this and which test would then be more appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues here, none of which are particularly specific to mixed models, but have to do with parameterization of linear models in R (and to some extent in any software for fitting linear models).

- The value on the left-hand side of the `~` is the response, or dependent, variable: since you say

> I'm interested in seeing how abundance of each species has changed over time in each place

I would think that `number ~ year + type` would be more appropriate (i.e., `number` is the response variable)

- when you specify `~ year + type` you are fitting an *additive* model, i.e. the model assumes that fruit types have difference baseline values but that *all fruits change between years in the same way*. If `year` is a numeric (rather than a categorical, or `factor` variable in R), the value that R would give you for `typeApple` represents the predicted *difference* at year 0 (!) between whatever your baseline fruit is (usually the first *alphabetical* level, which makes it a little odd that you got a result for `Apple` ...) and apples.
- if you make `year` a factor and specify `number ~ -1 + type + year:type` then you will get separate estimates of the year effect for each fruit, which should be identical to what you get if you use the subset.  You could also consider the `lmList()` function ...

Example:

```
dd <- expand.grid(type=c("Apple","Cherry","Grapefruit"),year=factor(2001:2002))
dd$y <- 1:6
lm(y~-1+type+type:year,dd)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me out. I took your suggestions and put it back into the lmer as     

fit <- lmer(number ~ -1 + type+ (1|year:type) + (1|place), data = fruits, REML=FALSE ). This gives me results that are close to what I get with the subset but a little different. Is there any reason you used lm instead of lmer? How would I control for place using lm? Would I just add + place? Thanks so much again.